# What are the advantages of web driver over selenium RC?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, browser-automation, selenium-rc

Please provide answers in detail, So that we could clarify that which one is to choose, Web driver or Selenium RC.

Comment: Which one is better to use ?

Comment: I was thinking why a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781940/selenium-vs-webdriver-any-obvious-advantages has been voted much higher than this and now I see. The other demonstrates some knowledge and experience shared.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this question I asked several months ago on stackoverflow can do some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781940/selenium-vs-webdriver-any-obvious-advantages
Although I said I decided to use RC at that time, I turn to webdriver short after that. Yes, webdriver has problems, but it is upgrading time after time. I would rather try the new features of webdriver developed by selenium groups, than using the old, end-of-life selenium.

Comment: I need the major differences between RC and web driver that why to use which.

Answer (score 3):

- Webdriver is faster, as compared to RC
- Webdriver mimics much more closer to real-life interaction; as compared to RC
- WebDriver supports more languages
- WebDriver is more actively followed/supported now; RC is past

details: http://www.guru99.com/introduction-webdriver-comparison-selenium-rc.html

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that a Webdriver and RC suites are they allow you to use a programming language in creating your test scripts (not possible in Selenium IDE).

Following programming languages are supported by WebDriver (but others have some 3rd party support)

- Java
- .Net
- PHP
- Python
- Perl
- Ruby

Where they differ;

WebDriver is faster than Selenium RC since it speaks directly to the browser uses the browser's own engine to control it

Selenium RC tends to be slower Than Webdriver since it uses a Javascript program called Selenium Core. This Selenium Core is the one that directly controls the browser, not you.

WebDriver can also support HtmlUnit.  A headless browser which is very useful in certain circumstances.

Comment: Looks like WebDriver is ideal and has no downsides, which isn't true according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781940/selenium-vs-webdriver-any-obvious-advantages

Comment: The "newness of SafariDriver" is less of an issue now than it was 3 years ago on that linked comment.  Is there a particular disadvantage you are thinking of and I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### 2017

You use webdriver.

RC is deprecated and no longer developed.